# Getting "The configuration file has changed. Run the "app:config:import" ...." during integration tests, after most of them ran already

Tags: magento2.3, integration-test

We are getting the below message just after lots of integration tests already ran properly.

How can this be caused?

```
Configuration: /var/www/dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml
II.........................EE.EE.                                 33 / 33 (100%)
Time: 2.45 minutes, Memory: 881.91MB
There were 4 errors:
1) Example\Foo\Test\Integration\CustomerDeactivationTest::testBar
Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The configuration file has changed. Run the "app:config:import" or the "setup:upgrade" command to synchronize the configuration.
```

*Edit*
It seems to happen because we use

```
$this->login();
$this->getRequest()->setMethod(Http::METHOD_POST);
$this->dispatch('customer/account/deactivate');
```

In the integration test...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in incomplete bootstrapping of the integration tests (aborted with errors), on the second run the bootstrapping worked, but only because it already was half installed - but the config stuff did not fully work then.

Comment: I my case, the bootstrapping worked. However, the test did not pass